# How to Stretch Remote Video to Fill Screen in React Native / WebRTC?

Tags: video, react-native, webrtc

I am using react-native-webrtc and am able to access the remote video and place it on my screen. However, the video only takes up a portion of my screen with white space above and below it.

The code is as follows:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.isConnected) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.stretchContainer}>
          <RTCView streamURL={this.state.remoteURL} style={styles.video1} />
        </View>
      );
    } 
}
```

With the following as `styles`

```
 stretchContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000',
    alignItems: 'stretch'
  },
  video1: {
    flex: 1
  }
```

I have also tried absolute positioning and setting the width and height through Dimensions. However, all of these approaches give the same result.

I think it's because the remote video has a width and height already associated with it (640 x 480), but I just want to stretch the video to fill the screen regardless of the resolution. Is this possible?

Comment: It looks from your code as if you are apply the stretch to the container for the video rather than to the video itself?

Comment: Any sample link or codepen or jsfiddle for your work?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the prop objectFit to 'cover'  like this:
`

```
<RTCView
     style={styles.localVideo}
     streamURL={this.state.localStream.toURL()}
     objectFit={'cover'}
/>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

using this piece of code always fill component in it's parent

`video1: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  }`

hope it will work for you